# Error running program - C

Tags: c, function, pointers

Where is the error running the program?
I know that there is a problem in the row of the loop FOR in the two functions.

I ran with the debugger and I do not know why there is the error.

The crash is:
Unhandled exception at 0x00E214E5 in program2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00E25865.

and then the program stops.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *what1 (char s[], char t[], int n);
int what2 (char str[], char c);

int main ()
{

    printf("%s\n", what1("hello", "world", 2));
    printf("%d\n", what2 ("fkbf", 'o'));

    return 0;
}


char *what1 (char s[], char t[], int n)
{
    char *p=s;
    while (*s++);
    for (--s; n-- && (*s=*t); s++, t++);
    *s='\0';
    return p;
}

int what2 (char str[], char c)
{
    char *ptr;
    for (ptr=str; *ptr;)
        if ((*str=*ptr++)!=c)
            str++;
    *str ='\0';
    return ptr-str;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: what kind of error? is it a crash? or unexpected return? or garbage print ? ...

Comment: I don't know which question about modification of string literals to choose, but it's clearly a duplicate question.

Comment: The crash is: Unhandled exception at 0x00E214E5 in program2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00E25865.

and then the program stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `what1()` and `what2()` are modifying strings passed as literals, that's undefined behavior since such strings can be stored in read-only memory.

Comment: i think that string is not read-only memory. why the string is read-only memory, and how can i change to write memory?